# How to merge results from 'groupby' operation on several different Dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dask

I read a series of csv files. Each contains a history of transaction data for a different user.  I want a summary of the amounts of the transactions by weekday for the overall group.  Doing the summary for each user is easy but I'm having a problem aggregating the results

For each user the data looks about like this:

```
id  data_import_id  posted  amount
00000000  3c221ff  2014-01-02T19:00:00.000-05:00  3656506
00000013  3c221ff  2014-01-02T19:00:00.000-05:00  3656506
00000015  3c221ff  2014-01-04T19:00:00.000-05:00  3656506
0000000a  3c221ff  2014-01-05T19:00:00.000-05:00  3656506
00000001  3c221ff  2014-01-06T19:00:00.000-05:00  3656506
```

I read the .csv files and build a list of Dataframes one for each user.  Then I process the Dataframes to first get a summary of amounts by week day and then try to aggregate the results over all the users.

The Dataframe list in cumulative looks like about like this for two users:

```
[           amount
weekday          
Monday      43118
Wednesday  5872780,             amount
weekday           
Friday        1249
Monday     2566648
Wednesday    12000]
```

From that list I want to generate a single data frame with just two columns, "weekday" and "amount" where amount is the total for a day over all the users.

The code I'm using is below and it gives a "ValueError: Unable to convert column amount to type class 'int' ".  I have also tried using 'append' and 'join' but could not get them to work possibly because the Dataframes are not all the same size.  TIA for any help/guidance.

```
def assess(df):
    # Create list to hold results
    cumulative = []
    for frame in df:
        # Produce a Dataframe that summarizes a users weekday totals
        total_amounts = frame.groupby(["weekday"])[["amount"]].sum()
        cumulative.append(total_amounts)
        print(cumulative)
        # *** The problem is here *** 
        cumulative.set_index("weekday").join(total_amounts.set_index("weekday"))
    return cumulative
```

Comment: You want the output in a list, or in a new dataframe? Would make more sense to create a new dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using `concat` then `groupby`

```
df=pd.concat(list_of_dfs,keys=np.arange(len(list_of_dfs)))
df['weekday']=df.posted.dt.day_name()
l=[y.sum() for x ,y in df.groupby([df.index.get_level_values(0),df.weekday])['amount']]
```

If need them in a dataframe

```
yourdf=df.groupby([df.index.get_level_values(0),df.weekday])['amount'].sum()
```

Comment: Tnx.  The reference to '.concat' clarified what needed to happen a lot; just the way my mind works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Series.dt.date_name` for this and pass that to the groupby function:

```
df_new = df.groupby(df.posted.dt.day_name())['amount'].sum()
```

---

```
print(df_new)
posted
Monday      3656506
Saturday    3656506
Sunday      3656506
Thursday    7313012
Name: amount, dtype: int64
```